# ion-slide-box not working in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

I'm trying to have a slide-box whenever you swipe to the left it go to next slide and when you swipe to the right it go back to previous page. I follow the instruction on Ionic website but it can not swipe to any direction.
Here my code:

Html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
     <h1 class="title">Test Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
   <ion-content style="color:grey;">
        <ion-slide-box>
            <ion-slide>
                <div>
                    "Hello slide 1"

                </div>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <div>
                    "Hello slide 2"
                </div>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: can you try this http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Kbpyg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ion-slide only works when you swipe through the content.

Replace your code with this

```
<ion-slide>
  <div class="slide">
   <p>Hello slide 1</p>
  </div>
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
   <div class="slide">
    <p>Hello slide 2</p>
   </div>
</ion-slide>
```

In style.css

```
  .slide{
  height:100vh;}
```